# Demonstration of the maximum product of the terms of an average

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I have this statement:

> If $\frac{a_1 + a_2 + a_3}{3} = p$, with  $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\},p \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and $p \neq 0$
>
> Prove this: $Max(a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot a_3) = p^3$

My attempt was:

Any term can be written in the form: $a_1 = p+a, a_2 = p + b, a_3 = p +c$

So, $p + a + p + b + p + c = 3p$, thus $a+b+c= 0$

Then, i need to prove: $(p+a)(p+b)(p+c) < p^3$

$(p^2+p(a+b)+ab)(p+c) < p^3$

$p^3 + p^2(a+b) + pab + p^2c +pc(a+b)+abc < p^3$

$p^2(a+b+c)+p(ab +c(a+b)) + abc < 0$, since $a+b+c=0$

$ p(2ab+2ac+2bc)+2abc < 0$, Multiply by $2$

$p[(a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)] + 2abc < 0$

$-p \cdot(a^2+b^2+c^2) + 2abc < 0$

But I don't know what else to do. Any hint is aprecciated and also i want to know the general proof of this $n$ terms. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Arthur, yes. I alredy edited the question

Comment: Have you heard about the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: Yes i heard about that

Comment: This is just the $n=3$ case for AM-GM: $\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3}{3} = p$, so Max$(\sqrt[3]{a_1\cdot a_2\cdot a_3}) = p$. Cubing yields Max$(a_1\cdot a_2\cdot a_3) = p^3$, with equality when $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = p$.

Comment: But the terms are not necessary equal